# Замерить время выполнения программы

Tags: c#, c, c++

Необходимо замерить время выполнения программы, написанной в MS Visual Studio
Как можно это сделать?
Внесение изменений в код не предлагать

Comment: `AQTime` / `dotTrace` / собственный профайлер в `VS2012`.

Comment: Программа читает из файла, преобразует информацию записывает в файл. По пути выполняет вывод на консоль(но никакого ввода с консоли, только файл)
Необходимо замерить время от момента запуска программы, до момента ее завершения.
Пример того, как это возможно виден в Code:Blocks
После окончания работы программы в консоль выводится строка
Process returned 0 <0x0>  execution ti,e: 3.129 s
При этом никакой коррекции кода я не произвожу.

Comment: Ну, так это отладочный вывод самой среды разработки... MSVS должен делать то же самое. Но при вызове программы другим способом вполне естественно, что эти данные не будут выведены таким образом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - если программа представляет собой нечто без интеракции с пользователем, то банально делаем программу, которая вызывает нашу программу, засекая момент старта или завершения. Т.е. то же самое, что и предложил [@Asen](/users/5040/asen), но вместо внутреннего MessageBox.Show(""); нужно поставить инструкция для запуска внешнего файла.

Дурацкий пример. Создаем командный файл `helper.cmd` следующего содержания:

```
 ; время до запуска программы
 echo %TIME%
 ; запускаем программу
 c:\path_to_prog\my.exe
 ; время по завершению программы
 echo %TIME%
 pause
```

Answer (score 8):

[[@Чистяков Владислав](/users/7136/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2)](/users/7136/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2), вот интересно, если вам надо замерить время выполнения программы без изменения кода, то зачем вы мешаете в одну кучу все си-подобные языки( и сам си )? Одно с другим как-то связано, по-вашему? На каком уровне вам надо измерить время выполнения? Ведь это можно сделать и на машинном уровне. Если уж вы сюда добавили тег "C#", то позвольте уж показать, как это можно сделать на нем:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 MessageBox.Show("");
 sw.Stop();
 MessageBox.Show((sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/100.0).ToString());
```

Answer (score 5):

Создать экземпляр `System.Diagnostics.Process` и вызвать метод `WaitForExit`. Запомнить время перед созданием процесса и после завершения вычесть из текущего времени.

Comment: Просил же - без изменений в коде любых. С изменениями - нагуглить элементарно

Comment: Здесь не предполагаются изменения в существущем коде. Это может быть  отдельная программа, запускающая существующую.
Но, вариант, сделать это уже имеющимися и проверенными средствами, по-моему приоритетнее.